I am having a problem with prettier extension in vscode. How to solve this?
["INFO" - 9:28:00 AM] Attempted to load Prettier module from c:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\MyCode\esbenp.prettier-vscode
["ERROR" - 9:28:00 AM] Failed to load module. If you have prettier or plugins referenced in package.json, ensure you have run npm install
["ERROR" - 9:28:00 AM] Cannot find Prettier package.json
Error: Cannot find Prettier package.json
I already tried searching for a possible solution. if it's not too much to ask, may i have a detailed guide to solve this?

Have you tried running an npm install in the cli at the root directory (same directory as package.json file).  If yes have you looked in your node modules to see if prettier package is there?  If not delete node modules and re install
